# NPM registry API, view a package's internal structure and file's through a JSON response

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cdn

Is it possible using the NPM registry API to request an endpoint such as

```
https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery
```

And view the Tarbells structure and internal files without having to actually download the package in a JSON response such as:

```
{
  files: {
   js: registry.npmjs.org/v1/jquery@3.1.1/jQuery.min.js,
  },
}
```

I am trying to understand how CDN's work and I am confused on how [jsdelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/) is able to actually list out all the actual **.js**, and other file extensions to a permanent URL such as:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js.

Is jsdelivr actually downloading all these Tarbells and storing them? **Is there a way to view the actual jQuery.min.js file through the NPM registry endpoint?** I have read many resources, and can't for the life of me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, jsDelivr actually stores the files locally. For the files that they don't have cached locally, every file they have ever served is stored in a global S3 storage, which can be fetched upon demand [[source](https://www.jsdelivr.com/network)].

jsDelivr also has a neat infographic showing how files are fetched.

[image: infographic]

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to respond. I had saw that diagram it was interesting. But what I am confused about is say you are going to jsdelivr and searching for a package not in their database, but is on NPM. Are they literally querying NPM's registry, downloading the package, extracting the contents, and then serving their results. That seems counter productive.

Comment: Yes, _if_ no one has _ever_ requested that version of that package before. It has to be done at some point, and if you're the first, then so be it. The key is they cache everything they've ever served.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this response. If you could maybe tell me another possible alternative to view NPM's actually files inside tarbells without downloading that be great.

Comment: I'm not aware of any, unfortunately. Some packages have a `files` key in the package.json, though it's far from universal. The only other thing I can think of is to track down the GitHub repo if one exists and list files from their API.